# Rolled files get erased on restart with log4j

Tags: file, log4j, restart

I have a web app that logs using log4j.

Here's the config :

```
log4j.logger.apppackage.app=INFO, app
log4j.appender.app=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.app.File=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-6.0.14-3/logs/app.log
log4j.appender.app.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.app.Append=true
log4j.appender.app.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.app.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%C{1}-%t] %m%n
```

Using this configuration, the app.log file will roll at midnight correctly.

Today I stopped the app, looked at the files, and there were 4 or 5 rolled files.

I restarted the app, and all the rolled files disappeared!

I was under the impression that the "`Append=true`" setting was there to avoid that?

How do I keep the rolled logged files when I restart the app?

Comment: From the configuration you've given here, you shouldn't have any problems. So I'm guessing the files don't get deleted by log4j, but by Tomcat. You're logging into the Tomcat log file directory, it seems. Have you tried setting the path to something completely different, outside of Tomcat?